# How to turn off ConfirmableTrait in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to switch off `ConfirmableTrait` in Laravel 5.

On my production server I have many jobs, some of them prompt alert `"Do you really wish to run this command?"` and for that reason job is failed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide an example command and also indicate which OS you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit `ConfirmableTrait` like this

```
public function confirmToProceed($warning = 'Application In Production!', $callback = null)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

second way override `confirmToProceed` method add in your job or create new trait file and use them

```
public function confirmToProceed($warning = 'Application In Production!', $callback = null)
        {
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: It is bad practice to edit something what is in VENDORS. This trait is in core of laravel: Illuminate\Console.

Comment: @AdamKozlowski override  `confirmToProceed` trait method

Comment: I will check it